# CoffeeScript How to know which class this.variable refers

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm wondering if there is a way to know which class's prototype is referred in the code below.

```
class Foo
  test : ->
    console.log "This is from Foo"
  test2 : ->
    console.log "This is from Foo"

class Bar extends Foo
  test2 : ->
    super

class Baz extends Bar
  constructor : ->
    @test() # this refer to Foo's test directly
    @test2() # this refer to Bar's test2 but end up calling Foo's test2
```

Both Baz's `@test()` and `@test2()` refer to `Bar`'s test and test2.and Since there is no `test2` prototype in `Bar`, @test2 refer to `Foo`'s
`test2`.

My question is, Is there any way to know which prototype is refered when I call @something in a multiplex nested class.

desired result I want to get is

```
@test -> Foo
@test2 -> Bar (It's perfect If it's able to detect it's ended up calling Foo's test2)
```

Comment: `@test2() # this refer to Foo's test directly`. It calls `Bar::test2` and then `Foo::test2` because you call `super`.

Comment: You can always look at [`@constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) to see what `@` is but what you seem to be trying to do smells a bit off. Perhaps a more realistic example would help.

Comment: @mu_is_too_short thats current class's own properties.isnt it? and my question is when you do NOT have properties you call with @. it starts looking up prototype chains.my question is how to know which class is referred if the called property is in the prototype chains.